# How to update a Database Field table using a Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures

I basically have a database table, which has a field called DESCRIPTION

My table is called "Table123"

Each record is a phrase that can be repeated.

I have 10 records in this table, and in the field DESCRIPTION i have the phrases: "hello, are you okay?" four times, "goodbye and thank you" four times, and "have a nice day" two times.

I want to change this phrases by using a stored procedure, because i cant change directly the database table.

I want to change this : in the first phrase i want to change to "For example: hello, are you okay?" in the four records, and in the second phrase i want to change to "Hello and thank you" in the four records.

I have basically to create a STORED PROCEDURE that changes a part or a word of the phrase in the description field.

Any help?

I am working in SQL management studio

I have tried:

```
USE [XXX]

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateTable]  

      @XKey                  INT,
      @XDescription          NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    begin transaction
        begin try             
            set nocount on

 UPDATE table  

 SET           
        Description = @VMDescription       
 WHERE  ID = @VMKey

commit; 
        end try
        begin catch
            rollback transaction;

            declare @errorMessage nvarchar(4000);
            declare @errorSeverity int;
            declare @errorState int;

            select 
            @errorMessage = ERROR_PROCEDURE() + ': ' + ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @errorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            @errorState = ERROR_STATE();

            RAISERROR(@errorMessage,@errorSeverity,@errorState);
        end catch
END
```

Comment: What have you tried? And why didn't it work?

Comment: Also, what rdbms are you working with?

Comment: @HoneyBadger and Zohar updated the post

I did that, but don't know how and when to change the text of the field description...

Comment: Google for `CASE`WHEN` with `UPDATE`. You need something along the lines of `SET Description = CASE Description WHEN 'hello, are you okay?' THEN 'For example: hello, are you okay?' WHEN 'goodbye and thank you' THEN 'Hello and thank you' ....`.

Comment: I tried alex but id don't work, i dont know if i am putting that in the wrong place

Can you add it to my code above and post it in a response for the cases in my question? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you have specific values to update, then just use

```
UPDATE table
   SET description = 'For example: hello, are you okay?'
 WHERE description = 'hello, are you okay?'

UPDATE table
   SET description = 'Hello and thank you'
 WHERE description = 'goodbye and thank you'
```